# Multiple controller instances in angular.js, javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a view that consists of the two same parts, only the content is different. So, basically I want to somehow use one controller and one view for both left and right parts.
What I do (in html):

```
<div class="board_body">
    <div class="left_board" ng-controller="leftBoardController">
        <div ng-controller="panelController" ng-include="template"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right_board" ng-controller="rightBoardController">
        <div ng-controller="panelController" ng-include="template"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I keep all initialization logic in left and right controllers and use panelController and it's view for left and right parts. In this case panelController can be shared because it uses common $scope variables that have different values (vars are created in the left and right controllers so they are visible to the panelCotrl).

```
angular.module("radar.leftController", [])
.controller("leftController", function ($scope, ...) { 
    $scope.data = getSomeData();
}

angular.module("radar.rightController", [])
.controller("rightController", function ($scope, ...) { 
    $scope.data = getOtherData();
}

angular.module("radar.panelController", [])
.controller("panelController", function ($scope, ...) { 
    $scope.template = "somePath/panelView.html";
    // shared logic for left and right contrls goes here
}
```

In the panelView.html:

```
<div>data: {{data.length}}</div>
```

Seems that from the right I can change both left and right vars, but from the left I can only change the left vars (as expected). (I need left and right parts be completely separated).

So, what is a proper way of reusing one controller (creating multiple instances)?

Comment: Looking at it real quick, what you are doing should work. What do you mean when you say that from the right you can change both left and right vars? Can you post a more complete example on plunkr?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this would be to use [directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) with isolated scopes. 
Then your code would look like so:

```
...
angular.module("radar.panel", [])
.directive("panel", function() {
   return {
    scope: {'panelData': '=' // Doubly bound to panel-data attribute},
    templateUrl: 'somePath/panelView.html'
    controller: function ($scope, ...) { 
      // shared logic for left and right contrls goes here
    }
  }
}
```

```
<div class="board_body">
    <div class="left_board" ng-controller="leftBoardController">
        <div panel panel-data="data"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right_board" ng-controller="rightBoardController">
        <div panel panel-data="data"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a lot of controller re-use using Angular's `controllerAs` syntax - see [this](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) article by Todd Motto.

However, I think a better way would be to keep shared functionality between controllers inside a service/factory/provider and keep your controllers lean.

Comment: Hi, this question was asked more than a year ago)) Now we have controllerAs, even without it we can reuse controllers/templates. And this is not bad, it saves a lot of lines of code, for instance in my current project we're reusing one controller/template in 7 places (I mean the routs are different). Regarding the code in this post yeah, it's better to have different controllers for each panel and share data via a service. Now I mabby would use only one controller and avoid ng-include. I need to close this question)